# Do I need to remove a lead riser from my toilet flange area to install a PVC flange?

Tags: toilet, lead, flange, cast-iron

I am replacing my toilet and after researching I found the flange is covered by a lead riser that is bent, folded, over the flange to hold it down.  I unbent it so I could remove the flange before I read what that was.  Should I put the flange back and peen down the lead?  Can I cut the lead down to the floor with a Sawzall and put a PVC Oatey that has the expanding ring flange?  Or, do I really have to remove the whole thing down to the cast iron pipe, add new PVC pipe insert, etc.?

Comment: What is the condition of the old flange?

Comment: Looks ok.  I thought it was supposed to be PVC nowadays.  I'm thinking I can put the old one back now.  I don't know if there is a new metal one I can use.

Comment: You would only have to replace it it the old one was broken.  If it's in good shape and mounted on top the the existing floor, there's no need to replace it.